# How can I increase marginLeft onclick in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, margin-left

I want to begin my onclick() function in javascript `style.marginLeft=0` to be like start from **'0px'**  to **'-100%'** to **'-200%'** and then at the end with **'-200%'**, when It become '-200%' **If you click It again**, It will bring you **back to** `.marginLeft='0'`
[Code on Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/packy/1Lmyvuof/135/)

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
var u = -100;
function addMargin() {
  var current = x.style.marginLeft = u + '%';
  if (x.style.marginLeft == -200) {
    x.style.marginLeft = '0';
  } else {}
}
```

```css
#container { display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 100%; height: 150px; white-space: 
             nowrap; overflow: hidden; }
.box { width: 100%; height: 150px; 
       display: inline-block; position: relative; }
.box:nth-child(1) { background: lightblue; }
.box:nth-child(2) { background: red; }
.box:nth-child(3) { background: green; }
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='box'>1</div>
  <div class='box'>2</div>
  <div class='box'>3</div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Next>" onclick="addMargin()" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can step-down with 100 at each iteration and use modulo operator (`% 400`) for a reset

Here is an example:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
var u = -100;

function addMargin() {
  x.style.marginLeft = u + '%';
  u -= 100
  u %= 400
  console.log("margin-left:", x.style.marginLeft)
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  background: lightblue;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  background: green;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='box'>1</div>
  <div class='box'>2</div>
  <div class='box'>3</div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Next>" onclick="addMargin()" />
```

Comment: You mean `%= 300`?

Comment: @blex op has said "_when It become '-300%' If you *click It again*_".. so it should be 400 (to let -300 pass)

Comment: You're right, not sure whether that's what they want, but they did say it

Comment: sorry guys, I'm wrong. but thank you all for all your help. It should go back to first div (box)(1) I misunderstood It should be "-200%" at div(box)(3)-> go to div(box)(1)

Answer (score 2):

Condition match was wrong you need validate with some external count variable instead of matching `marginLeft`

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
var u = -100;

var count = 1;

function addMargin() {
   count = count%3;
   x.style.marginLeft = count * u + '%';
   count++;
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition:all 0.8s ease;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  background: lightblue;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='box'>1</div>
  <div class='box'>2</div>
  <div class='box'>3</div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Next>" onclick="addMargin()" />
```

Comment: thank you so much. I misunderstood on marginLeft '-300%' but you're very intelligent!

Comment: Glad to help ! @itti

Answer (score 1):

This is the cleanest/most compact implementation I could think right now. As other people said, the key is to use the [Remainder Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder).

Additionally, please use `addEventListener`/`removeEventListener` API as it has been by many years the correct way to handle events.

```js
const box0 = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];

box0._current = 0;

function addMargin() {
  box0.style.marginLeft = `-${++box0._current % 4 * 100}%`;
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', addMargin);
```

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  white-space: 
  nowrap; overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  width: 100%; height: 150px; 
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  background: lightblue;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='box'>0</div>
  <div class='box'>1</div>
  <div class='box'>2</div>
</div>

<input id='button' type="button" value="Next>" />
```